# ANOVA post hoc test OR t test?

Tags: anova, t-test, post-hoc

Suppose I have three groups, control, treatment A, and treatment B. I performed ANOVA with post hoc analysis (Tukey test) on the three groups and found that the ANOVA significant, control - treatment 1 significant, but control - treatment 2 not significant. However, when I use t-test on control - treatment 2, I got a significant result (p<0.05).

Suppose I am interested in control - treatment 2. Should I report ANOVA post hoc result or t-test result? They give a completely opposite conclusion.

Comment: Search your books and the web for "alpha inflation" or "alpha error cummulation" or "multiple comparisons problem" and you will find that $\alpha=0,05$ is no longer the magical limit for your t-test, if you want to compare it to the posthoc tests. Eg. https://webstat.une.edu.au/unit_materials/c7_anova/oneway_problem_alpha.htm or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonferroni_correction

Comment: It is not correct to say “completely opposite”. Failing to find significance is not the same thing as proving there’s no difference. Absence of proof is not proof of absence.